# Error importing import { Observable } from "rxjs"; Angular 14

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular14

New to Angular... I'm using Angular 14. Writing my first component. I added my first Observable and the minute I added the import:

```
import { IMenuItem } from "./IMenuItem";
```

I get two error messages:

> Error TS2585  Build:'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to es2015 or later.
>
> Error TS1219  Build:Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

I comment out that import and my Observable code and the error goes away...

Here is my component code:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { IMenuItem } from "./IMenuItem";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenuService {

 // Temporary hard coded localhost into URL for the API for testing
 private menuUrl = "http://localhost:7075/api/v1/menu";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getMenuItems(): Observable <IMenuItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMenuItem[]>(this.menuUrl);
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if this issue is environmental. I may not have something set up correctly.

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.8
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 8.11.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.10
... core

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1400.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular       14.0.3
@angular-devkit/core                14.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics          14.2.8
@angular/animations                 14.0.3
@angular/cli                        14.2.8
@angular/common                     14.0.3
@angular/compiler                   14.0.3
@angular/compiler-cli               14.0.3
@angular/forms                      14.0.3
@angular/platform-browser           14.0.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   14.0.3
@angular/platform-server            14.0.3
@angular/router                     14.0.3
@schematics/angular                 14.2.8
rxjs                                7.5.5
typescript                          4.7.4
```

Any help would be greatly apprenticed.

UPDATE

Here is the contents of my tsconfi.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
   "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

I set the experimentalDecorators = true, as the error message suggestions but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Do you happen to have a Promise type in the IMenuItem file?

Comment: @WesleyTrantham No, it is a simple interface with number and string properties.  Basically, an ID, Label and a URL.

Comment: @RodneyHickman `ctrl + shift + p` in vs code and give `restart ts server` then check if the second error goes away!

Comment: @NarenMurali, I'm using Visual Studio Professional.  I've rebooted my computer and it doesn't go away. Thanks

Comment: When all else fails you can also delete your node_modules folder and then run `npm i` again. On a rare occasion `npm clean cache` also can help.

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but have you tried to do exactly what is stated in the error messages? Like adjusting your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: has you import `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` in the main.module?

Comment: @WesleyTrantham Thanks for the suggestion. I tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it.  This also didn't help. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus Thank you for the suggestion. I did try that and also rebooted my visual studio professional but the error is still there.  I updated the question to include the tsconfig.json contents.

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for the suggestion. I checked and my main component app.componet.ts has the HttpClientModule included.

Comment: You mean you checked app.module.ts (not app.component.ts), right? And have you also added HttpClientModule to imports array?

Comment: Do you get the same error, if you just write `public getMenuItems() { return this.http.get(this.menuUrl); }` or if you only add some observable property `s!: Observable<string>;`?

Comment: As soon as I ran Visual Studio as an administrator the problem went away. Don't know why.

Comment: @Torila I did get the same error writing public getMenuItems() { return this.http.get(this.menuUrl); } . Thanks for the suggestion.